# Generating JSON object of the tests ran using Protractor?

Tags: json, protractor, automated-tests, mocha.js, yadda

I'm relatively new to end to end testing with `Protractor`, `Mocha` and `Yadda` (for integration with `Mocha` so I can use `Gherkin` and step definitions).

I've seen a plugin called `Mochawesome` which generates an HTML report which can be viewed offline, along with this JSON object of the test results, all of which contained in a 'reports' folder.

I presume it's `Mochawesome` which generates these JSON objects as the HTML page seems to have corresponding tags etc. Is there any way to generate a JSON object of the tests ran without the HTML reporter? The idea was to create my own sort of 'dashboard' containing information about the tests based on the JSON information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can create a `JSON report` of your specs/tests with protractor.You just have to put `resultJsonOutputFile: './Report.json'` in your config file.

your config file should somewhat look like this:

```
exports.config = {

directConnect: true, 
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
baseUrl: 'http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/', 
framework: 'jasmine2', 
specs: ['*spec.js '], 
allScriptsTimeout: 180000, 
getPageTimeout: 180000, 
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 180000
},
 resultJsonOutputFile: './Report.json', // It would create report.json file in your current folder
 onPrepare: function () {

    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
}
};
```

You can consume this `json report` and use it in your way!

Comment: the `resultJsonOutputFile` thing worked.  thanks!   now i can create report, from command line, using that.   unblocked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about generating JSON object directly in protractor. But what i know is that, we can  generate results in XML and then convert xml to json by writing some customized code.

Code for generating XML reports are as follows:

```
     framework: "jasmine2",
     onPrepare: function() {
        var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters'),
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
             savePath: '../result/',
             filePrefix: ‘report’,
             consolidateAll: true
            });
         );
     },
```